# How do I use mediawiki's api

Tags: php, api, authentication, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Base url: http://localhost/mediawiki

Mediawiki's login page: http://localhost/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

Successful login using mediawiki's login page is as follows:

**Request Data**

> Request URL:http://localhost/mediawiki/index.phptitle=Special:UserLogin&action=submitlogin&type=login&returnto=Main+Page
>   Request Method:POST
>   Status Code:302 Found

**Form Data**

> wpName:Testuser
>   wpPassword:testpass
>   wpLoginAttempt:Log in
>   wpLoginToken:10acc6b49eed071636cf7b940fe154b0

---

**Problem**
I have attempted to do the same in a jquery ajax request but I am missing the *wpLoginToken* in the *Form data*

Here are some of answers/docs about mediawiki and auth

login requests
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Structure_of_login_request

API - login
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=login

plugin - login
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aExtAuthDB

depricated answer
[MediaWiki Authentication from external form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106611/mediawiki-authentication-from-external-form)

I have learnt that I need to use the *mediaWiki API* with the following parameter configurations 
    `action=query&format=json&meta=tokens&type=login`
to first retrieve a token (note the docs say that action=login is no longer supported) then continue.

I do not know how to use this API. I have tried attaching it to the base url with some intuitive modifications

http://localhost/mediawiki?action=query&format=json&meta=tokens&type=login

http://localhost/mediawiki/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=tokens&type=login

http://localhost/mediawiki/includes/api/ApiMain.php?action=query&format=json&meta=tokens&type=login

None of these worked. Please if anyone can shed some light onto my situation it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You getting should token with first request. and then pass it to your next requests.

Comment: i'm not getting a token with any of the urls i have, it returns either no such action or page not found

Comment: Please clarify more details about your problem.
First ensure your API is actually working. Try to make GET request http://localhost/mediawiki/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&titles=Main_Page
Does it return json with wiki text of your Main Page? (you may use another page from your wiki).
Then tell if you use GET or POST when trying to retrieve a token?
What tool do you use for that? Browser? Browser extension? Fiddler? A program written by yourself?

Comment: If you use a recen MediaWiki version, visit the `Special:ApiSandbox` page, it will help you piece together a correct API request.

Comment: @kinORnirvana I believe it's as you said, my API isn't working, as for tools i use the browser and POSTMAN.

Comment: @Tgr I've been to the sandbox and that's where I got some of the urls from, it's just that when I change it to suit my installation I get 404 or no such action

Comment: Did you use your own wiki's sandbox page? If the sandbox itself works, the generated URL should too. If it doesn't, chances are it will give you an error message describing what needs to be enabled.